What does the word "solid" mean in the context of detective work when talking about an aspect of a crime
This context comes from the movie "The Game" 1997 (No spoilers)
It's a situation in which someone hired a detective to investigate an elaborate prank being played on the client. The detective reports back about his findings. Please answer both questions in the end if you know the answers.

Client: What about the house?
Detective: The graffiti was an oil-based marine marking solution, illegal in the States. It's not impossible to trace but it'll take time.
The photo, the gun, the clown, the ambulance. It's all pending. Breaking and entering we've got solid.

solid(adjective)
: RELIABLE
a solid performer(Merriam-Webster)
solid(adjective)
certain or safe; of a good standard; giving confidence or support:
This provided solid evidence that he committed the crime.
The drama course gives students a solid grounding in the basic techniques of acting.(Cambridge Dictionary)
2 questions:

Does this mean that the detective has reliable evidence that what transpired in the client's house was in fact a burglary? Can only the fact that someone broke in can be gleaned from that (not who did it)?

Is "solid" an adjective in this case?



I would understand it to mean that they have solid (firm) evidence that the perpetrator was guilty of breaking and entering, but other aspects of the case are still awaiting forensic analysis. Compare Cambridge's first example.

The word "solid" is a noun in the cited context (abbreviated from "solid evidence", as @KateBunting says). But note that this meaning only applies in very specific situations where it's contextually obvious that the word "evidence" has been "elided". In typical AAVE (and other "informal / dialectal" registers), use of "solid" as a noun normally implies the word favour has been elided (as in "Hey, bro! I need you to do me a solid.")

@FumbleFingers - would you say that 'bang to rights' functions as a noun or adjective in 'We've got him bang to rights', Sarge'?

@MichaelHarvey: I always assumed it was banged to rights, but I see from that linked chart that I'm much in the minority on that one. The difference is purely orthographic to me, since I'd be incapable of enunciating that past participle (or of hearing it, even if someone else insisted they were enunciating it! :) Whatever - since I think of it as a past participle, it's natural for me to parse it as an adjectival usage.

@FumbleFingers - but not 'we've got breaking and entering [solid/certain/definite/robust]?'

@FumbleFingers Not sure why you're bringing in AAVE. The detective is not speaking AAVE. Not by a longshot. solid is being juxtaposed with pending.

solid proof of a crime in everyday parlance. "Do someone a solid" in American English is not limited to AAVE.

if someone said "Hey, bro! I need you to do me a solid", I'd suspect they were asking me to produce a turd for them.

Dude, coprophilia is not that common to be assuming that off the bat. I've heard it being used by a famous comedian Bill Burr and I don't think he's into that, well ... sh*t.


Does this mean that the detective has reliable evidence that what transpired in the client's house was in fact a burglary? Can only the fact that someone broke in can be gleaned from that (not who did it)?

You've got the general idea correct. The wording "Breaking and entering we've got solid." means that the 'breaking and entering' charge is reasonably certain. It is implied that other options/charges are unlikely or unrealistic.
As for your second question, I believe FumbleFingers has you covered in the comments of your question.

My position is that solid in the cited context is a noun, because it's short for solid evidence. The containing sentence effectively has unstated leading and trailing elements [Regarding the criminal actions] breaking and entering, we've got solid [evidence]. I don't think solid is an adverbial element structurally equivalent to, say, Breaking and entering we've got fully covered (which would be a somewhat unidiomatic 'inversion' of We've got breaking and entering fully covered).

It's not "short for 'solid evidence'". For that to be the case, it wouldn't be "Breaking and entering" but a prepositional phrase like "For breaking and entering" or "On breaking and entering" or "With breaking and entering" -- i.e. in respect to breaking and entering.

@TimR: Your own example We're all out of guavas and mangos. Bananas we have strikes me as a deliberately quirky inversion (intended to allude to Yes, we have no bananas as "endearingly unidiomatic foreigner"?). Most native Anglophones would say [but] we have bananas in such contexts. But at the end of the day I think this one's a matter of opinion, and we've all said what we think, so that's enough.

@FumbleFingers   It's not a "quirky invention" but a well-attested fronting of the object.   "Time we have aplenty!"  https://www.google.com/books/edition/UniTazia/4zRYJtKqELUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22we+have+aplenty%22&pg=PA158&printsec=frontcover

"Organizations we have aplenty -- what is lacking is a visionary idea ..."  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reclaiming_Liberty/3Doaq5nd8sMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22we+have+aplenty%22&pg=PA255&printsec=frontcover

The fronting of the object (inversion of normal SVO order) occurs in connection with a contrast being drawn between two juxtaposed elements.

If you're studying for an exam, you can say

I have chapters 1 to 6 down pat.

The practical meaning is that you know that material well.
Similarly, if  a detective says about the criminal charges of "breaking and entering":

Breaking and entering we've got solid.

or

We've got breaking and entering solid.

the practical meaning is that as far as those charges are concerned, we have substantial evidence to prove them.  We have those charges well-substantiated.
In contemporary grammatical terms these are considered object complements and inasmuch as they express the state the subject has the object in, they are adjectival.
P.S. As a native speaker of American English, I do not think the detective's remark could be punctuated like this:

Breaking and entering --  we've got solid.

The detective's speech is not clipped to that degree but is quite articulate. Rather, that sentence is simply inverted with the object "breaking and entering" in foregrounded position since the detective is contrasting those (well-substantiated) lesser charges with the more serious and more difficult to prove "pending" charges. Compare:

We're all out of guavas and mangos. Bananas we have.

The inversion of normal subject-verb-object order occurs in connection with a contrast being drawn between two elements in context that are juxtaposed.  Compare:

Time we have aplenty!

https://www.google.com/books/edition/UniTazia/4zRYJtKqELUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22we+have+aplenty%22&pg=PA158&printsec=frontcover
and

Organizations we have aplenty -- what is lacking is a visionary idea ..."

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reclaiming_Liberty/3Doaq5nd8sMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22we+have+aplenty%22&pg=PA255&printsec=frontcover
[It's not that this inversion occurs only with aplenty, either. Someone who knows the COCA or similar corpora search interface (I don't) should be able to find {NOUN} we have {end of sentence} or {NOUN} we have {complement} {end of sentence}].

Cogs, we're all out. But sprockets, sprockets we got.
[imaginary example]
Cogs, we're all out. But sprockets, sprockets we got up the wazoo.
[imaginary example]

And it's not a case of the detective using the word solid as shorthand for the noun-phrase "solid evidence". solid there is being juxtaposed with pending.  If he had been using it as a shorthand for the noun phrase "solid evidence", he would said something like:

On breaking and entering, we've got solid.

or

For breaking and entering, we've got solid.

It's not that  this elliptical version is impossible:

Breaking and entering -- we got solid (evidence).

The detective is being terse but not that terse.
